# Eliminate underscores and convert to lowercase MySQLselect query column names

Tags: mysql

I am stuck at what seemed to be a very simple task in MySQL.

I have a `table A` with fields `A_Id` and `A_Name`.

MySQL query - `SELECT * FROM A;`

Obviously, in the output, the column names are `A_Id` and `A_Name`. But I want them to be `aid` and `aname`, that is, **eliminating all underscores and converting to lowercase only the column names**.

I think this should be possible. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

EDIT:
Why do I need to do this?

I have indexed all these fields in ElasticSearch, and then querying using Spring Data Elastic, using named queries becomes difficult when there are underscores in the field names

I did look around for some answers, but all of them are either `ALTER` statements or manipulating the field values using `REPLACE`, none of which suit my usecase.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `AS` keyword to change the column names in the output:

```
SELECT A_Id as aid, A_Name as aname
FROM A;
```

There's no simple way to do this automatically for all columns, you need to list each column specifically. The only way to automate it would be to write a stored procedure that created the query dynamically by querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

The query to get the columns would include something like:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(column_name), ' AS ', REPLACE(LOWER(column_name), '_', '')) AS select_list
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'A';
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid `AS` because I have tens of columns in my table. I haven't written a stored procedure before, can you point to some useful links?. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why can't you just use the column names as they are?

Comment: Google "mysql stored procedure tutorial" and you'll find some sites.

Comment: I have indexed all these fields in ElasticSearch, and then querying using Spring Data Elastic, using named queries becomes difficult when there are underscores in the field names

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table for examples of stored procedures that prepare queries dynamically.